# Created a PyPi package, but can't import modules after installing

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi

I have a project structured like this:

```
.
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── setup.py
└── src
    ├── __init__.py (with name="packagename")
    ├── module1
    │   ├── __init__.py (with import for each code file)
    │   └── (several code files)
    └── module2
        ├── __init__.py
        └── (similar structure to module1, total of 4 modules like this)
```

I've created the dist files and uploaded them to TestPyPI and installed into a test project. I want to be able to import modules such as `import packagename.module1`, but it gives me `No module named packagename`.

My `setuptools.setup` params in `setup.py` contain entries like this:

```
packages=["packagename"],
package_dir={"packagename": "src"},
py_modules=["packagename.module1", "packagename.module2" ... ]
```

Any idea why I can't seem to import after installing the package?

I have various example test scripts outside of src in the project where I can access the modules as `from src.module1 import ClassName` (though it would be nice to replace `src.module1` with `packagename.module1` when importing if possible).

Answer (score 5):

`py_modules` is for declaring **single-file** modules located at the root of your project.  Subdirectories of your package directory like your `module1` and `module2` need to be declared by listing them in `packages`:

```
packages=["packagename", "packagename.module1", "packagename.module2" ...]
```

Comment: Hmm, I've just updated my packages entry to be ["packagename", "packagename.module1", ...] but I still can't seem to import, whether it's "from packagename import module1", "import packagename *" etc.  I've also tried "from module1 import Class1" but to no avail. 

If I go to site-package directory (test project) and find the dir "packagename", I can see the __init__.py containing "name='packagename'" and directories containing the four modules, which in turn have all of their code. The __init__.py in each module has imports for each class in the module (from packagename import Class1...).

Comment: @bingecoder: `packagename/module1/__init__.py` exists in your `site-packages` and you still can't import it?  Are you sure you're running the same Python version as you installed the package under?

Comment: 2.7.15 in the package project and test project. In setuptools.setup classifiers I have ""Programming Language :: Python :: 2"

Comment: I'm wondering if I might just have some confusion about the process to install. I've run "python -m pip install --index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ packagename" and it installs (to /home/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-package), but is there an additional step I'm missing before I can import?  I'm using pycharm and normally I just use the project interpreter gui to find and install packages, so maybe that performs some steps for me that I'm not doing as part of this manual process (this is my first time trying to do deployment in Python).

Comment: UPDATE: It looks like if I go into Python via the terminal and "import packagename" I don't get an error...so this has to be an issue with my test project not seeing the installed package I think. I looks like I can create instances of my classes and everything in the terminal...

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem with needing to install by using the python command via the virtual environment I was using (as opposed to the one I had active in the terminal at the time I installed my package) rather than a problem with my packaging!